# Launching Huawei Petal Maps Directions via Intent on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Is it possible to launch Huawei Petal Maps with navigation from point A to point B using intent just like in google maps? If yes, how?

Comment: As relevant team confirmed, they have not put it into the road map about when will Petal Map available in India region by now.The team will make it available in more regions to serve more people when all conditions are met.We will update you about progress. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use an intent to launch the Petal Map app, and then use navigation functions in the app.

- Deep link example:

```
mapapp://navigation?saddr=xxx&daddr=xxx&language=xx&type=xxx
mapapp://navigation?saddr=home&daddr=company&language=en&type=drive
mapapp://navigation?type=exit
```

- To use this function, you need to set **uriString** to the following:

```
"mapapp://navigation?saddr=25.102916,55.165363&daddr=25.164610000000,55.228869000000&language=en&type=drive"
```

- Sample code after modification:

```
String uriString = "mapapp://navigation?saddr=25.102916,55.165363&daddr=25.164610000000,55.228869000000&language=en&type=drive"; 
Uri content_url = Uri.parse(uriString); 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, content_url); 
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
     startActivity(intent); 
}
```

For more details, see [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/petal-maps-application-navigation-0000001060038018).

Comment: Thank you! This is the exact answer I was looking for. Also, thanks for linking the docs for Petal Maps navigation. I was not able to find it before.

Answer (score 0):

As it would seem from this [link](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/content/en-us15766210/), India is currently not among the supported regions for Huawei Petal Map. Currently, you would not be able to use it for navigation.